# Can an app purchased and installed using a specific email id be updated by a different id?

Tags: windows-10, minecraft, software-update, microsoft-store

I have Minecraft windows 10 edition but it is purchased from my friend's id which he used to download the game in my PC and then signed out and removed his id. I want to know if I will be able to update it from my own outlook id with which I am signed in to the MS store!

Comment: No; You won't even be able to play it.  If you wish to play Minecraft on your system you will have to purchase it.

Comment: @Ramhound But I can play it and it work's fine with my Xbox live id signed in